# How can I get jqGrid to display the right record count when doing rowspan?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I've been using jqGrid for some time now and am getting pretty good at using it, it's a fantastic tool.  I'm getting into more advanced uses now and have run into a problem I can't seem to figure out.  I've built a grid that uses a "rowspan" which has been discussed in other Stackoverflow questions.  The problem I'm having is that the pager displays the wrong record count and page counts based on the number of records loaded.  Each and every row in my grid spans exactly two rows, so the page count and record count is always double the size of the number of displayed rows.  Is there some hook into the grid that will allow me to provide the number of records should actually displayed or change what is being displayed?

I appreciate any help that can be provided.

Comment: Could you simply alter the total, page, and records values that you are passing down to your jqGrid?

Comment: The count is based on the local array's data.  I'm assuming that the grid uses "data.length" to determine how many records are available.